# add one column to the other columns of the same dataframe in sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` like this

```
column1 column2  column3 column4...columnn
1        xx       cc      Nan       aa
2        xx       cc      gg        aa
3        xx       Nan     gg        aa
```

What I want to do is to add `column1` to the other `column` in parallel and delete column1. I do not want to add column1 where values are Nan

So I want as output the following

```
 column2  column3 column4...columnn
   1xx       1cc      Nan... 1aa
   2xx       2cc      2gg... 2aa
   3xx       Nan      3gg... 3aa
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apply with axis 0 to perform the same operation on each column or a selection of columns:

```
(df.loc[:, df.columns != "column1"]
   .apply(lambda x: df["column1"].astype(str) + x, axis=0))

# Out:
  column2 column3 column4
0     1xx     1cc     1gg
1     2xx     2cc     2gg
2     3xx     3cc     3gg
```

Comment: thank you. I update my question. just one comment for your consideration What if I had nan values? In that case i do not want to add column1

Comment: @redplanet still works, you will get nan also in the result

Answer (score 1):

```
df['column2'] =   df['column1'] + df['column2']
df['column3'] =   df['column1'] + df['column3']
df['column4'] =   df['column1'] + df['column4']
df.drop(columns=['column1'])
```

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't throw a TypeError?

Answer (score 1):

Tauqeer Akhtar has the right idea but you need to typecast it to string before concatenation.

```
column1 = df['column1'].astype(str)
df['column2'] = column1 + df['column2']
df['column3'] = column1 + df['column3']
df['column4'] = column1 + df['column4']
del column1
df.drop(['column1'], axis=1)
```

Comment: yes he should adjust according to the `data type` of the dataframe column

Comment: Thank you. What if I had many columns? So what if I had column1 to column50 for example. How to automatically perform this procedure? I mean that is difficult by hand to add so many columns

Comment: I wll also update the questions

Comment: updated the answer as you want

Comment: are you sure it is necessary to explicitly account for nans? what happens if you add two string columns, where one of them contains some nans? -> the latter effectively being an object column

Comment: you are completely right. That would give you nans regardless.